# Setting up Thinking Sphinx in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I'm trying to set up [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) in my Rails 3 app, but I am getting a "Routing Error".

I set up MySQL and installed Sphinx without error.  My gemfile contains:

```
gem "riddle", "~> 1.5.0"
gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 2.0.10"
```

These install without a problem.
My model contains:

```
define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes acad_field
    indexes expertise
    indexes interests
    indexes experience
    indexes marital_status
    indexes email
    indexes place_of_birth
    indexes birthyear
    indexes hometown
    indexes current_residence
    indexes languages
    indexes nationalities
    indexes ethnicities_mom_dad
    indexes institution
    indexes program
end
```

and my index action in my controller contains:

```
def index
 @profiles = Profile.search params[:search]
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.json { render :json => @profiles }
 end
end
```

This is what my routes look like:

```
match "profiles?search=:search", :to => "profiles#index"
```

When I try running a search by typing the search criteria URL directly into the browser, I get this error:

```
Routing Error

undefined method `define_index' for #<Class:0xb3ada670>
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Did you run [`rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild`](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/deltas.html) before trying to search?

Comment: @sarnold you know, i looked at a bunch of tutorials, that didn't go over that step. thanks

Comment: Does it solve the problem? If so either add it to an answer and accept it, or reply and I'll add it so you can accept it. (I was blindly shooting in the dark. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `rake thinking_sphinx:rebuild` fixed my "undefined method" problem.

Comment: Also restarting the rails app.